# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dailyconfirmed')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what's problem with my code i am  getting error while accesing mydata.dailyconfirmed after page reloading?

```
 const[state,setState]=useState({});
async function getApiIndia1(){
   const temp=await fetch('https://data.covid19india.org/data.json')
   const mydata=await temp.json();
   setState(mydata)
}
useEffect(() => {
    getApiIndia1();
}, [])
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown are you accessing a property called `dailyconfirmed`, or accessing any property on `mydata`.  Which line throws the exception?  When you debug, what is the runtime value of the variables used on that line?  What do you expect them to be?  Why?  Can you update the code to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `mydata` outside of `getApiIndia1` (which I assume you are trying to do). It is only defined in that block, which is the reason why you're using state (essentially to save the required data globally). mydata can't be found and that's why it's throwing an error.
What you should do instead is access `state`, which is where you're storing that data.

But that will still throw an undefined. That's because of the issue that previous answers have already highlighted. You need to access `state.cases_time_series.dailyconfirmed`. That should give you the data you want.

It's always a good idea to check API responses carefully. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update the setState

```
setState(mydata.cases_time_series)
```

and when you wish to find dailyconfirmed, loop over your state which is basically an array of object.

```
state.map((dailyconf)=>{
if(dailyconf?.dailyconfirmed) console.log(dailyconf?.dailyconfirmed)
})
```